# Unable to upload file to folder in Google Drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api, python-3.6

I'm trying to upload a local file to a a specified folder in Google Drive, and I'm only successful in getting it uploaded to Drive, not in the folder I'm telling it to. I've tested with a shared folder as well as a non-shared folder and I'm getting the same result. No error, just the file being in the root Drive directory.

```
    creds = GetGoogleCredentials()
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    # Call the Drive v3 API
    FileSearch = service.files().list(q="name='{0}'".format(file), fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    items = FileSearch.get('files', [])
    FolderID = 'IDHere'
    if not items:
        file_metadata = {'name': file, 
                         "parents": FolderID
                        }

        media = MediaFileUpload('folder/en/' + file,resumable=True)
        service.files().create(body=file_metadata,media_body=media,fields='id').execute()
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
```

Based off what I've found, the `"parents": FolderID` entry should be what I need, but it's like the `create` method is ignoring it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to upload a file to the specific folder in Google Drive using Drive API v3.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis with python.
- You have already uploaded a file to Google Drive using your script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please modify `parents` in the object of `file_metadata` as follows.

#### From:

```
"parents": FolderID
```

#### To:

```
"parents": [FolderID]
```

- At Google Drive, a file has several parents. So in this case, the folder ID is set in an array.

#### Reference:

- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)

If this was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize.

Comment: Yep, that was it. I was understanding the documentation wrong. Thank you!

Comment: @Josh Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.